# Are these specified ranges a rule for the three types of port numbers?

Tags: networking, port

Various articles as well as the IANA site [1](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) have stated that the range of three types of ports is as follows:
**1-Well-known ports**:0-1023
**2-User ports**:1024-49151
**3-Dynamic ports**:49152-65535
but in Wikipedia in the Range section [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) says these ranges are just IANA's recommendation, and different operating systems use different ports for Dynamic ports.

Now the question that arises is whether the said ranges are a rule or a recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a policy for IANA assignments – e.g. if you ask IANA to register a port number, they will never choose one from the "dynamic" range.

(Keeping the ranges separate avoids port collision problems; e.g. a port can't be used to accept inbound connections if it *currently* happens to be in use as an ephemeral port by some outbound connection.)

However, there is no rule at protocol level; TCP can establish connections from any source port to any destination port.

In general, the *entire* "port assignments" table is just a recommendation (in order to reduce the chance for headache) but it is not enforced.

Comment: Well, are the suggested user ports different on different operating systems? I say this because the suggested range of dynamic range is different in different operating systems

Comment: Operating systems don't _make_ the suggestions – they either _follow_ the suggestions that come from IANA or don't.